# Jaalee Beacon developing

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-ibeacon

My Jaalee just got deliver today, and I would like to start developing. 
All I need to do is send back some data to the phone, when the button on the beacon is pressed, like Amazon Dash.

Unfortunately the official docs is a pos (piece of sh..), so I have downloaded the official app form the playstore (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jaalee.eBeacon), which is crashing,when I want to rename the beacon or simply exiting when I want to write data to the beacon.

Does anyone where has experience with Jaalee beacons Android SDK?

Comment: did you got the solution or able to integrate?

Comment: Sorry mate, I can’t remember. It was 3 years ago.

Comment: ok, thanks.
but if you get any reference in the meanwhile please comment

Answer (score 0):

In general, button on beacons are just here to turn on connectable mode, you **cannot** catch any callback when buttons are pressed.

Please look at your documentation.